# How to use a Google Maps link to show a map?

Tags: html, google-maps

I'm developing a website where the users can fill a textarea where besides various text, they can copy/paste a Google Maps link.
At the moment I'm able to recognize and catch those links, the next step would be to use them to show the corresponding map on another page.
The problem is that it seems that I can't use the link as generated by the Google Maps page, an example:
`https://www.google.it/maps/place/Roma+RM/@41.9099856,12.3955722,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x132f6196f9928ebb:0xb90f770693656e38!8m2!3d41.9027835!4d12.4963655?hl=it&authuser=0`, but also many other various formats depending on what the user was looking for (a specific place, directions...)

If I try to put this link into an iframe like

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="<the_link_above>&zoom=17&key=MY_API_KEY"></iframe>
```

the map doesn't appear and looking into the browser's console I read `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: <the above link> does not permit cross-origin framing.`

A link which can be embedded has a different formatting, like `https://www.google.it/maps/embed/v1/place?q=<an address>&zoom=17&key=MY_API_KEY`

but I can't ask to the users to edit the link, they would just copy and paste what they get from Google as the website is not intended only for expert users, but for anyone.

Is there a method to use the link as generated by Google Maps or should I quit the idea to use it?

Comment: It would be nice if who votes down would leave a comment to justify that, next time I'll make the same mistake if I don't know what's wrong with the question.

Comment: Could you ( or have you thought already ) use the google static maps class?

Comment: Unfortunately, also GMaps Static needs a different link format than the one you get from a search on GMaps page and as explained, I can't ask to the users to modify the link.

Comment: understood! How about on the page that has the textarea have a map( fully featured with search & geocoding etc ) that allows the user to find what they are after - when happy with the map view they have chosen use that maps current settings to generate the map on another page?

Comment: I'll try to work on that, thank you.